# ORMLite examples for Android won't compile

Tags: java, android, sqlite, ormlite

I have been trying to work through the [HelloAndroid](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_7.html#SEC65) example for [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml) but haven't been able to successfully compile.  I am having a problem with the DatabaseHelper class.  Specifically the `getDao()` method:

```
/**
* Returns the Database Access Object (DAO) for our SimpleData class. 
* It will create it or return the cached value.
*/
public Dao<SimpleData, Integer> getDao() throws SQLException {
  if (simpleDao == null) {
    simpleDao = getDao(SimpleData.class);
  }
  return simpleDao;
}
```

Here is the compile time error I am receiving:

> *Type parameters of D cannot be determined; no unique maximal instance exists for type variable D with upper bounds com.j256.ormlite.dao.Dao,com.j256.ormlite.dao.Dao*

Comment: This looks a lot like the following [bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=98379). The compilation works in eclipse, but not with normal java compiler because of a type inference problem. How are you compiling the code ?

Comment: I am using the IntelliJ IDE from JetBrains running in Ubuntu 10.

Comment: I agree with you @Mademoiselle Geek (cool name).  Hey curtisthibault, what version of Java are you using on your Ubuntu.  It looks like this is fixed in 6u24-rev(b22) and 6u25(b01).

Comment: @Gray Looks like I am running `1.6.0_22`.  I'm running Ubuntu in a VM and I've been putting off upgrading to 11.10.  This looks like a good time for that upgrade.  I'll let you know if the new version of Java fixes it.  Thanks

Comment: Cool.  If it fixes it then @Mademoiselle Geek, you should turn your comment into an answer so he can accept it.

Comment: @curtisthibault is it compiling now ?

Comment: @Mademoiselle Geek: It was a problem with my Java version. If you turn your comment into an answer I'll mark it as the answer.  Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got a similar error when trying to build my ormlite project using Netbeans:

> Compiling 15 source files to ~/NetBeansProjects/Main/build/classes
>       Main.java:74: type parameters of D cannot be determined;
>       no unique maximal instance      exists for type variable D with upper bounds 
>       com.j256.ormlite.dao.Dao,com.j256.ormlite.dao.Dao
>       pcDao = DaoManager.createDao(connectionSource, PC.class);

Due to the comments I switched my Java Platform from OpenJDK 1.6 to Oracle's JDK 1.7.0_02 and it resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
public class HelloAndroid extends OrmLiteBaseActivity<DatabaseHelper>
{
    private final String LOG_TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "creating " + getClass() + " at " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        doSampleDatabaseStuff("onCreate", tv);
        setContentView(tv);
    }

    /**
     * Do our sample database stuff.
     */
     private void doSampleDatabaseStuff(String action, TextView tv)
     {
         // get our dao
         RuntimeExceptionDao<SimpleData, Integer> simpleDao = getHelper().getSimpleDataDao();
         // query for all of the data objects in the database
         List<SimpleData> list = simpleDao.queryForAll();
         // our string builder for building the content-view
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
         sb.append("got ").append(list.size()).append(" entries in ").append(action).append("\n");

         // if we already have items in the database
         int simpleC = 0;
         for (SimpleData simple : list)
         {
             sb.append("------------------------------------------\n");
             sb.append("[").append(simpleC).append("] = ").append(simple).append("\n");
             simpleC++;
         }
         sb.append("------------------------------------------\n");
         for (SimpleData simple : list)
         {
             simpleDao.delete(simple);
             sb.append("deleted id ").append(simple.id).append("\n");
             Log.i(LOG_TAG, "deleting simple(" + simple.id + ")");
             simpleC++;
         }

         int createNum;
         do
         {
             createNum = new Random().nextInt(3) + 1;
         }
         while (createNum == list.size());
         for (int i = 0; i < createNum; i++)
         {
             // create a new simple object
             long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
             SimpleData simple = new SimpleData(millis);
             // store it in the database
             simpleDao.create(simple);
             Log.i(LOG_TAG, "created simple(" + millis + ")");
             // output it
             sb.append("------------------------------------------\n");
             sb.append("created new entry #").append(i + 1).append(":\n");
             sb.append(simple).append("\n");
             try 
             {
                 Thread.sleep(5);
             }
             catch (InterruptedException e)
             {
                 // ignore
             }
         }
         tv.setText(sb.toString());
         Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Done with page at " + System.currentTimeMillis());
     }
}
```

Comment: What is the solution?  What did you change in the example to answer @curtisthibault's question?  Can you explain it a bit more please?